# Nginx serving the wrong root with SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two nginx vhosts which are identical apart from the domain and the SSL/root locations. They look like this:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.co.uk

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.co.uk;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain1.co.uk/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen               80;
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          www.domain1.co.uk;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/domain1.key;    
    return 301 $scheme://domain1.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name domain1.co.uk;

    root        /var/www/domain1.co.uk/public_html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/domain1.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location /blog/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ ^/api {
        try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @prerender {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token 4398455894u5ugjgfgfj;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_|prerender=1") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_pass http://service.prerender.io;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
    }

}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.co.uk

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.co.uk;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain2.co.uk/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen               80;
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          www.domain2.co.uk;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain2.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/domain2.key;    
    return 301 $scheme://domain2.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name domain2.co.uk;

    root        /var/www/domain2.co.uk/public_html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain2.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/domain2.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location /blog/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ ^/api {
        try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @prerender {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token 4398455894u5ugjgfgfj;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_|prerender=1") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_pass http://service.prerender.io;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
    }

}
```

When I visit `domain1.co.uk` it just works as expected, and redirects to the non-www https URL. If I visit `domain2.co.uk` though, it serves the correct SSL cert, but is showing the domain1 site on the domain2 URL.

I have a default server block as well:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
    return 444;
}
```

How can I configure this so that domain2.co.uk is actually serving the files from `/var/www/domain2.co.uk/public_html` instead of domain1?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Sorry! I thought, you didn't have `domain2.co.uk`. Hoping you have "`/var/www/domain2.co.uk/public_html`" as root for "`domain2.co.uk`" server. Did you make nginx to read the /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.co.uk file, if it is not included. Basically, you would need to check the "include" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and also, create a sym link file "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain2.co.uk" and point it to "/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.co.uk" to enable it.

Comment: That's exactly what I have. The main block of code is what I have in two files for two domains i.e `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.co.uk` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.co.uk`

Comment: I have the symlinks and the nginx.conf has `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` which seems correct to me. I'm a bit stumped :/

Comment: Oh! Now it is hard. okay, did you reload the nginx service after the changes? and also, any chance that, you have pointed domain2.co.uk to root of domain1 initially and your browser cached it?

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. I was using Nginx as a reverse proxy for a NodeJS app and both files do `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;` which points to the same application.

Comment: Aha! Glad you find it :)